# Node app can't find module when run on Heroku dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a node.js app, an API, that works with `heroku local` yet does not run at a remote dyno. Specifically, it fails with the following message after being built:

```
2018-02-19T21:19:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ---
2018-02-19T21:20:01.874321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-02-19T21:20:01.588534+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user ---
2018-02-19T21:20:01.588534+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c3f854a0 by user ---
2018-02-19T21:19:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-02-19T21:20:03.954335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-19T21:20:05.841898+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] Starting
2018-02-19T21:20:06.353423+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-19T21:20:06.353446+00:00 app[web.1]: > saasaato-backend@1.0.5 start /app
2018-02-19T21:20:06.353449+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/server.js
2018-02-19T21:20:06.353451+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443156+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:544
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443160+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443161+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443165+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/server.js'
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443171+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443173+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443175+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-02-19T21:20:06.443177+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
2018-02-19T21:20:06.448738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-02-19T21:20:06.449100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-02-19T21:20:06.450147+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! saasaato-backend@1.0.5 start: `node dist/server.js`
2018-02-19T21:20:06.450299+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-02-19T21:20:06.450518+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-02-19T21:20:06.450686+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the saasaato-backend@1.0.5 start script.
2018-02-19T21:20:06.450842+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-02-19T21:20:06.458437+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-19T21:20:06.458601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-02-19T21:20:06.458706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-19T21_20_06_451Z-debug.log
2018-02-19T21:20:06.518039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-19T21:20:06.535280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

A previous heroku release of this app works but I'm unable to figure out what has gone wrong. I have tried setting heroku to not cache any files, double-checked node & npm versions, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm starting with `{ ..., "scripts": { "start": "node dist/server.js" }, ... }` in package.json and `web: npm start` in Procfile. Notably, I didn't chance anything in either package.json, Procfile, server.js or app.js before it broke...

Comment: I think its relative path issue, try changing script as follows: `{ ..., "scripts": { "start": "node ./dist/server.js" }, ... }`

Comment: Thanks, but it still fails in the same way...

Comment: @kgangadhar I just recalled that I had added `/dist` to my .gitignore. The app now works without that line, i.e., after I `git push heroku master` the sources along with the dist folder generated on my local machine. Heroku logs say "Build succeeded" and no errors. What do you make of this?

Comment: As per your start command i can say your main file `server.js` present inside `dist` folder and to start your application its must and should. since you added it in `.gitignore` that folder and server files were not pushed to heroku, As a result you were getting this error. That was the main cause.

Comment: I see that I've completely misunderstood Heroku. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I thought I was supposed to push only sources and Heroku would then compile etc. the app on the remote server. Thanks for your help, @kgangadhar!

Answer (score 0):

Your application script is as follows:

```
"scripts": { 
   "start": "node dist/server.js" 
}
```

As per your start command, i can say your main file `server.js` present inside `dist` folder and to start your application its must and should.

Since you added it in `.gitignore` that folder and server files were not pushed to `heroku`, As a result you were getting this error. That was the main cause.

`.gitignore` is mainly used to avoid pushing files like `node_modules` , unit_test reports and coverage, and log file to your git repository. you should not add your main file which was cause this issue till now. See this for more on [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) files